# adding n removing row in table with unique id of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

here's a demo table

```
<table id="table1">
<tr>
<td><label>name</label><input type="text" id= "name1"/></td>
<td><label>age</label><input type="text" id= "age1"/></td>
<td><input type="button" id= "addRow"style="background-image:url("images/addicon.png");"/></td>
</tr>
```

and jquery code m trying is

```
 $("#addRow").live("click", function (e, index) {
 var val = ("#table1 tr").length();
 val++;
    $('#table1  tbody > tr:last').after('<tr><td><label>name</label><input type="text" id= "name"'+val+'/></td><td><label>age</label><input type="text" id= "age"'+val+'/></td><td><input type="button" id= "addRow"style="background-image:url("images/addicon.png");"/></td><td><input type=button  id="deleteRow" style="background-image:url("images/removeicon.png");"></td>');
  });
  $("#deleteRow").live("click",function(e,index){
     $(this).parent().closest("tr").remove();
  });
```

Now problem comes when somebody add a row 2 times and delete a row 
i.e val will be name2, name3
suppose name2 is deleted 
then again adding row  no. of rows is 2 so val++
result in 3
and new row will have name3 as id, this is creating problem for me.
What actually i want is, I should maintain the row count 
1 2 3 ... like this irrespective what row is deleted.
Can anyone help me out with this, I have gone through loads of tutorial but none of them have maintained a uniform rowcount that's y i have put up this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use input names like `name[]` to have an array of values in the form.  This is easier than using things like `name1`, `name2`, etc.  If your concern is the labels, you can wrap an input in a label and skip the `for`, like so:

```
<label>String: <input></label>
```

Clicking `String:` focuses the input.

If you want to stick with what you have, just store `val` one scope outside of `.click` and increment it every time.  Don't rely on the length.

---

By the way, you should also switch from `.live` to `.on` assuming it's available.

Comment: hi, m new to website designing, can u help me with how to create array like name[] ur talking and automatically getting unique id's i tried giving name[] but when i add a new row it'll display id of every element as name[], the condition is to have unique id is must for me, approach can be any..

Comment: @virender just write it as `<input name="name[]">`.  Why do you need an id for every input?

Comment: there's a component m using which rely on id of the input, this is just a demo table but in actual the unique id condtion is must, if 2 id are same then wrong data gets filled.

Comment: @virender I wasn't suggesting that the IDs be the same, I was suggesting leaving off the IDs.  If you absolutely need them, just store `val` in a different scope

Comment: that worked man Thanks.. but still m confused if i'm asked to keep the naming uniform then what'll i do, anyways for now it's resolved

Comment: hey buddy sorry man m new here n looks like i dont have that much reputation to upvote it